# UITextView highlight all matches using swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

I want to highlight all matches word with searching. I wrote code but I couldn't use a loop. When i search a word, my app find words and highlight only first word. here is my code

```
var count = 0
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: txtMetin2.attributedText)
let text2 = txtArama.text as NSString
let text = txtMetin2.text as NSString
var range:NSRange
var checker:NSString = ""

for(var i=0 ; i<text.length - text2.length-1 ; i++)
{        
    range = NSMakeRange(i, text2.length)
    checker = text.substringWithRange(range)
    if(text2 == checker)
    {
        count++    
        let highlightedRange = text.rangeOfString("\(text2)")
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(), range: highlightedRange)
        let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        let textAttachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
        attributedText.appendAttributedString(textAttachmentString)
        txtMetin2.attributedText = attributedText                               
    }
}
println("\(count)")
```

i am very new at swift. sorry for bad coding. my codes find matches count but how can i highlight all matches thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Obligatory [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) based solution.

```
let searchString = "this"
let baseString = "This is some string that contains the word \"this\" more than once. This substring has multiple cases. ThisthisThIs."

let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)

var error: NSError?
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)

if let regexError = error {
    println("Oh no! \(regexError)")
} else {
    for match in regex?.matchesInString(baseString, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.utf16Count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: match.range)
    }

    textView.attributedText = attributed
}
```

Comment: It is not working when i am searching symbols like dot and question marks  '.' '?'

Comment: @ArunKumarP It is a regular expression, so you'd need to escape them in your search string. e.g. `stuff\\?` or `stuff\\.`.

Comment: @MickMacCallum .Yes it is working, but how I make the search string with escape in Swift (search string type is String)

Comment: Thank you! The best solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that with us. Amazing solution.

Comment: @ArunKumarP  Check out the class function `NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: whateverSearchTerm)` -- this automatically escapes whatever needs escaping for a case like this.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the following function passing the search input and the current content. that will return a `NSAttributedString?` that you can set in your `TextView`

### Swift 3

```
func generateAttributedString(with searchTerm: String, targetString: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: targetString)
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchTerm, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: targetString.utf16.count)
        for match in regex.matches(in: targetString, options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range) {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFontWeightBold), range: match.range)
        }
        return attributedString
    } catch _ {
        NSLog("Error creating regular expresion")
        return nil
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

highlight with diacritic insensitive option:

```
func generateAttributedString(with searchTerm: String, targetString: String) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: targetString)
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchTerm.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current), options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: targetString.utf16.count)
        for match in regex.matches(in: targetString.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current), options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range) {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFontWeightBold), range: match.range)
        }
        return attributedString
    } catch {
        NSLog("Error creating regular expresion: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4 & 5**

```
func generateAttributedString(with searchTerm: String, targetString: String) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: targetString)
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchTerm.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current), options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: targetString.utf16.count)
        for match in regex.matches(in: targetString.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current), options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range) {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold), range: match.range)
        }
        return attributedString
    } catch {
        NSLog("Error creating regular expresion: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have strings [ "Hi", "Hi.", "Hi there." ] and my search term is "H." it highlights "Hi" for all the strings. Is that normal?

Comment: Hi, @SleepNot I think my Solution solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I want to little improve the solution provided by @Barath and @Bruno Paulino, as this solution won't work with **escaped characters** like **{}[]()'"**, this solution works with escaped characters, this solution written in SWIFT 5.

```
func generateAttributedString(with searchTerm: String, targetString: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: targetString)
    do {

        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:  NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: searchTerm).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).folding(options: .regularExpression, locale: .current), options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: targetString.string.utf16.count)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.clear, range: range)
        for match in regex.matches(in: targetString.string.folding(options: .regularExpression, locale: .current), options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range) {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
        }
        return attributedString
    } catch {
        NSLog("Error creating regular expresion: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uitextview highlight  all matches word swift 3.0

```
 let searchString = "Lorem Ipsum"
 let baseString = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard .Containing LOREM IPSUM passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem IPSUM"



let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)
    do
    {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString,options: .caseInsensitive)
        for match in regex.matches(in: baseString, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.characters.count)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
            attributed.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
        }
        self.txtView.attributedText = attributed
    }
```

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrD4S.png)

Comment: Please add a description what the intention of your code is. It helps to understand the sample much better.

Comment: What can I do if I want to highlight more words from the baseString?

Answer (score 2):

Improved customized solution for Swift 4.2

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    convenience init(base: String,
                     keyWords: [String],
                     foregroundColor: UIColor,
                     font: UIFont,
                     highlightForeground: UIColor,
                     highlighBackground: UIColor) {
        let baseAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: base, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
                                                                                  NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: foregroundColor])
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: base.utf16.count)
        for word in keyWords {
            guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: word, options: .caseInsensitive) else {
                continue
            }

            regex
                .matches(in: base, options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range)
                .forEach { baseAttributed
                    .addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: highlighBackground,
                                    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: highlightForeground],
                                   range: $0.range) }
        }
        self.init(attributedString: baseAttributed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

this is new :

```
var count = 0
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: txtMetin2.attributedText)
let text2 = txtArama.text as NSString
let text = txtMetin2.text as NSString
println("\(text.length)")
println("\(text2.length)")
var range:NSRange
var checker:NSString = ""

for(var i=0 ; i <= text.length - text2.length ; i++)
{
    range = NSMakeRange(i, text2.length)
    checker = text.substringWithRange(range)
    if(text2 == checker)
    {
        attributedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(),
            range: range)
        let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        let textAttachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
        attributedText.appendAttributedString(textAttachmentString)
        txtMetin2.attributedText = attributedText
        count++
    }
}
println("\(count)")
```

i used range variable instead of highlighted range in attributedText.addAtrribute()