# How can I show the marked text from one textfield as marked text in other textfield in Xcode, swift 2

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I have two textfield having two texts in my OS X program. I would like to have the following effect. When I marked part of text in one textfield I would like to have the identical marked part of the text in other textfield. How can I implement this in xcode and using swift 2?

Comment: what do you mean by "marked"?

Comment: i.e. highlighting the text

Comment: not sure if possible, what would be the reason for wanting this...maybe there's another way to achieve this.

Comment: It is possible, I have seen this in other program. The reason is following. I have found that string AATTCGGCTT (placed in one textfield) is present in other string acagactgacAATTCGGCTTacgaa (placed in other textfield) and I would like to see the position of the smaller string by its highlighting in the bigger string. It is very useful in molecular biology. Ideally, dynamically, when I marking text it is immediately showing it in other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525171/uitextview-highlight-all-matches-swift

Comment: Thanks! In the link it is not exactly the case I would like to have.

Comment: u want highlighted instead of color. right? just figured it seemed very close that you could adapt it to your needs

Comment: Yes,highlighted instead of color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two TextViews (note: class NSTextView not NSTextField) and connect them to a view controller using outlets. Again, connect the innermost TextView, not the clip view or bordered scroll view. In the example below "searchView" is the one that contains the text you select, and "textView" the one which contains the text you want to highlight.

Then, you can do something like this (note that I tested this in Swift 1.2)

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {


    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!
    @IBOutlet var searchView: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "selectedSomeText:", name: NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification, object: searchView)
    }

    @objc func selectedSomeText(notification: NSNotification) {
        let selectedRange = searchView.selectedRange()
        if selectedRange.length > 0 {
            let nsString = searchView.string! as NSString
            let selectedString = nsString.substringWithRange(selectedRange)
            let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: selectedString, options: nil, error: nil)
            let foundRanges = regex?.matchesInString(textView.string!, options: nil, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count(textView.string!)))

            let firstFound = foundRanges![0] as! NSTextCheckingResult
            textView.showFindIndicatorForRange(firstFound.range)
         }
    }

}
```

This will highlight the first found match. You can then implement buttons or something to iterate though matches (for example, by storing "foundRanges" somewhere and iterate its index using buttons, etc). You might also want to implement some error checking and/or optional chaining because all those nils and forced downcasts in my example might cause crashes.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful !  It is working well. I have used for loop to highlight all positions through the array of NSRanges.