# Swift + Search for a string and go (set focus) to its ocurrence

Tags: swift, uitextview

i am a newbie in Swift so please forgive my ignorance.

I am doing a Book App with a lot of chapters.
I have provided the ability to add and save a bookmark. I show this bookmark string on a label. On click of this bookmark i am able to go to the chapter that has this saved bookmark.
I used some of the code in the accepted answer here [UITextView highlight all matches using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525171/uitextview-highlight-all-matches-swift) for reference.

The problem that i am facing here is:
1. I am unable to shift focus to that bookmarked string on that chapter.

Like for example: I have saved a bookmark on the end of chapter-1. The next time i click on the bookmark, i expect to go to that saved bookmark location i.e the end of the chapter. What i have achieved till now is hghlight that bookmarked location.In this case since the bookmark is in the end of the chapter, i still need to scroll down to get to my bookmark location.

Could please some one tell me how this can be achieved? 
(I am using Swift 2 and I have the text of the bookmark and the text range of this bookmark.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the CGRect of the highlighted text using:

```
let highlightRect = textView.firstRectForRange(highlightRange)
```

Then scroll focus to the CGRect with:

```
textView.scrollRectToVisible(highlightRect, animated: true)
```

If you need to convert an `NSRange` to a `UITextRange` in order to use the `firstRectForRange` method. Use something like this function:

```
func convertRange(range: NSRange, forTextView textView: UITextView) -> (UITextRange){
    let beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument
    let start = textView.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: range.location)!
    let end = textView.positionFromPosition(start, offset: range.length)!
    return textView.textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end)!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I actually had textRangeLocation and textRangeLength. So i could create a NSRange type.  `let createRange : NSRange = NSMakeRange(textRangeLocation, textRangeLength); `But this is not accepted by firstRectForRange().

Comment: I added a function to halt convert NSRange to NSTextRange. So for you, `highlightRect` would become `textView.firstRectForRange(convertRange(createRange, forTextView: textView))`

Comment: That worked. After you mentioned the method `scrollRectToVisible`, i looked for other methods of textView, and this one - `textView.scrollRangeToVisible(createRange)` helped me set focus on the entire range of the bookmarked text. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would be easier :P haha. No worries