# Does UITextView have a String which stores all words as text?

Tags: ios, textview, swift3

Does a `UITextView` have just one `String` which contains all words as a text? I am curious about an idea which I came up with. Can I do something to words added into the UITextView? Like am I able to detect offensive words or bad words by making an array?

If I have an array called `myArray`. Inside this array, for example, 'badword1', 'badword2', and 'badword3' are stored. If words of these are inputed.

My thought was in the following;

1. create a `UITextView` called `myTextView` and set over a
   `UIViewController`, and then connect `myTextView`.
2. Create an array called `myArray`. Inside this array, prohibited words are stored.
3. maybe....by using a for-loop, like

   ```
   for words in myArray {
       if myTextView.contains(words) { 
           print("words are found")
       }
   }
   ```

   I do not think this code works, but it is my guess.

Thanks.

Comment: UITextView has a `text` property ...

Comment: @MartinR can I highlight words which are found in a text view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension for String

```
extension String{
    func contains(_ text: String, substring: String) -> Bool {


        return text.range(of: substring, options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal) != nil
    }
}
```

Then you can do this-

```
for words in myArray {
if myTextView.text.contains(words) { 
    print("words are found")
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Aryan. Also, let me question one more thing. When such words are found, I want them to be highlighted. How am I able to do it?

Comment: Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525171/uitextview-highlight-all-matches-using-swift)

Comment: The property is `textView.attributedText` requires a `NSAttributedString` you cans et that to the words

Comment: `String` has already a `contains()` method and that is what you call in `myTextView.text.contains(words)`. Your extension is completely superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

@AryanC The better way to do is following:

```
func contains(text: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: text, options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal) != nil
}
```

Because you are making extension so you can make use of it by using `self`