# Is it possible to hightlight one word in the text?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to highlight one word of a sentence which is defined in xxx.strings file, such as highlight "Allow" in sentence "Please click Allow".

Comment: Yes. You can use AttributedString

Comment: A `.strings` file is for localization and is a poor choice to store a list of words. You better use plain text and split by line, or plist file

Comment: You can also use HTML in your strings to highlight text. Then you read it into a NSAttributedString using the init?(html:.... initialiser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView highlight all matches using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525171/uitextview-highlight-all-matches-using-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making text bold using attributed string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496093/making-text-bold-using-attributed-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use NSAttributed String to apply different attributes to your string like

**underline**

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
    let range = (self.text! as NSString).range(of: "your string you want to highlight")
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,NSAttributedStringKey.underlineColor : .white], range: range)
    yourlabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**change string color(forground color)**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
    let range = (self.text! as NSString).range(of: "your string you want to highlight")
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red], range: range)
    yourlabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**change string color(background color)**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
    let range = (self.text! as NSString).range(of: "your string you want to highlight")
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor : UIColor.red], range: range)
    yourlabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

**change font**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
    let range = (self.text! as NSString).range(of: "your string you want to highlight")
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : fontyouwant], range: range)
    yourlabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello please refer below method:-

```
func underline() {
    if let textString = self.text {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)
        let range = (self.text! as NSString).range(of: "your highlighted string")
        attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.underlineColor : .white], range: range)
        attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

hope it will help you,
Thank you.